# Java дождаться завершения Runnable

Tags: java, многопоточность

```
//...    
Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
//do something
}
});
Thread.sleep(2000);
//...
```

Как подождать завершение данного Runnable, не хочется использовать `Thread.sleep();`?

Comment: Просто поместите весь последующий код в run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашей ситуации прекрасно подойдет `CountDownLatch`:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

new Thread(() -> {
    //что то там
    latch.countDown();

 }).start();

latch.await();
//что то там
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас что-то такое:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private void testTask(){
        //...    
        Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              //do something
          }
        });
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //...  
    }
}
```

То почему бы вместо `sleep` просто не вызвать колбек какой-нить?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    private void testTask(){
        //...    
        Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              //do something
              //....
              // task completed
              testTaskCompleted();
          }
        });
    }

    private void testTaskCompleted(){
       //...  
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что `testTaskCompleted` будет выполняться в потоке UI.

Comment: @PavelMayorov если это проблема, то можно завернуть же в `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: Завернуть что и куда? `testTaskCompleted` у вас и так туда завернут, в том-то и проблема.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не так прочитал. А в чём проблема? Этот код топикстартера. Видимо, ему это было необходимо.

Comment: Нет, это ваш код. Топиктартеру надо было дождаться завершения Runnable. И продолжить работу. В фоновом потоке.

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда зачем вы в своём ответе используете `runOnUiThread`, если нужно в фоновом потоке?

Comment: Потому что автору так нужно

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406116/return-a-value-after-activity-runonuithread-method в похожем случае советуют использовать FutureTask:

```
FutureTask<Object> futureResult = new FutureTask<Object>(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
}, null);

Activity.this.runOnUiThread(futureResult);
futureResult.get();
```

Comment: Я в программировании под android полный ноль, и хочется уточнить один момент: запуск рандомных задач в потоке для ui это хорошая идея?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov рандомных - плохая. Но есть задачи, которые в нем и нужно выполнять.